# Developer story says matches on hold due to missing work/education, but it's not missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

The developer story sidebar tells me:

> ### Your job matches are on hold
>
> #### Work experience / education
>
> At least one complete with a minimum of 2 technologies and 150 char. for responsibilities

But I have one education entry and multiple work entries, one of which is more than 1300 characters and has seven associated technologies.

I made a small change and re-saved, then added and removed a long dummy work entry, in case this was a caching issue, but the sidebar continued showing me this warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a bug caused by the markdown migration yesterday. To determine minimum length we need the raw markdown, which now has to be explicitly fetched from history.

The fix went out with build rev `2016.4.26.3512`, you should see the correct info in the sidebar now.

Comment: the bug still there, now( November 24, 2016) see screenshot below...

Answer (score -1):

the status is not completed yet... the bug is still there...

[image]